# How to start an Animation for each object independently(KineticJS)

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

i am using kineticjs

```
        for(var i = 0; i < playerData.length; i++)
        {
            (function(i){
                data = playerData[i];

                group = stage.get('#' + data.user_id)[0];

                    var anim = new Kinetic.Animation(function(frame){



                                        dx = group.getX() - data.posX;
                                        dy = group.getY() - data.posY;

                                        var dist = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);


                                        var angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);

                                        var speedX = Math.cos(angle) * moveSpeed;
                                        var speedY = Math.sin(angle) * moveSpeed;
                                        group.setX(parseInt(group.getX()) - speedX);
                                        group.setY(parseInt(group.getY()) - speedY);
                                        console.log(dist);



                    }, mainLayer);
                    console.log('animation started');
                    anim.start();

            })(i)
        }
```

I havea problem to execute an animation for each object, everytime I get a new data from the server i loop all the objects to move at new coordinates, but I can't understand how to execute an animation correctly, my objects dont't run all in the same time, they begin to stuck, so the question is: how can i start a new Kinetic.Animation and then stop it for each object successfully?

Comment: also where do i need to put the condition if(dist < 1){anim.stop();} ???

Comment: You shouldn't create multiple animations if you can help it. Since each of your objects is in the same layer and utilizes the same logic, you can just create one animation and run that. See below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if I am understanding your code correctly, you want to animate multiple objects at the same time, all of which are in the same layer.

The reason you are experiencing slowdown is because you have multiple animation objects. And so, what is happening is you are re-drawing the entire layer every time you move just one object.

So what you really want to do is restructure to something like:

```
var anim = new Kinetic.Animation(function(frame){ // one animation on outside controlling logic for playerData
    for(var i = 0; i < playerData.length; i++)
    {
        (function(i){
            var data = playerData[i];

            group = stage.get('#' + data.user_id)[0];

            var dx = group.getX() - data.posX;
            var dy = group.getY() - data.posY;

            var dist = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

            if(dist > 1){ //this takes care of the stop you are looking for
                var angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);

                var speedX = Math.cos(angle) * moveSpeed;
                var speedY = Math.sin(angle) * moveSpeed;
                group.setX(parseInt(group.getX()) - speedX);
                group.setY(parseInt(group.getY()) - speedY);
                console.log(dist);
            }
            else{
                console.log(group.getName() + 'stopped moving');
                //this.stop(); // maybe use this to stop animation?
            }
        })(i)
    }
}, mainLayer);

console.log('animation started');
anim.start();
```

This way you only redraw the layer once, giving much higher speed. Also, I'm not sure you need an anonymous function inside the for loop.

Comment: I hope framework support this. i.e. if multiple animations are defined, on each frame, merge active animations into one, and draw once.